# using an alternative string quotation syntax in python

Tags: python, string, syntax, quotations

Just wondering...

I find using escape characters too distracting. I'd rather do something like this (console code):

```
>>> print ^'Let's begin and end with sets of unlikely 2 chars and bingo!'^
Let's begin and end with sets of unlikely 2 chars and bingo!
```

Note the `'` inside the string, and how this syntax would have no issue with it, or whatever else inside for basically all cases. Too bad *markdown* can't properly colorize it (yet), so I decided to `<pre>` it.

Sure, the `^` could be any other char, I'm not sure what would look/work better. That sounds good enough to me, tho.

Probably some other language already have a similar solution. And, just maybe, Python already have such a feature and I overlooked it. I hope this is the case.

But if it isn't, would it be *too hard* to, somehow, change Python's interpreter and be able to select an arbitrary (or even standardized) syntax for notating the strings?

I realize [there are many ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214881/can-you-add-new-statements-to-pythons-syntax/217373#217373) to change statements and the [whole syntax in general by using pre-compilators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065966/unable-to-understand-a-statement-about-customizing-pythons-macro-syntax/1066027#1066027), but this is far more specific. And going any of those routes is what I call *"too hard"*. I'm not really needing to do this so, again, I'm just wondering.

Comment: I'd've thought that having your choice of
'string'
'''string'''
"string" and
"""string"""

would've been enough for almost all situations. What am I missing?

Comment: @Blair Conrad, you're also missing the permutations of those strings with the prefix R, e.g. R"string".

Comment: @Blair actually you missed "maybe I overlooked it". ;-)

Comment: @Mark Ransom, true enough. and the ones with the prefix r. But I figured the rstrings were outside of the scope of the original question - it seemed to be more focused on the delimiters rather than embedded escapes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Python has this use """ or ''' as the delimiters

```
print '''Let's begin and end with sets of unlikely 2 chars and bingo'''
```

How often do you have both of 3' and 3" in a string

Comment: Not often, but it happens. Thanks a lot! :) - That's also much better looking than my weak suggestion. Freaking great it's there already!

Comment: @Cawas, that's not an uncommon reaction to Python. "Batteries Included" isn't the half of it.

Comment: On a related note, what's that syntax I see in some codes using `"""` to quote "comments" right below any `def`?

Comment: They are docstrings http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/ The standard way of documenting functions etc